# is there a way to bulk transform sdo_ordinates of polygon

Tags: oracle, transform, oracle-spatial

```
  SELECT
           LONGLAT(SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(
                    SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,82397,SDO_POINT_TYPE(LAT,LONGI, 0),NULL,NULL),
                    4326).SDO_POINT.X,
           SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(
                    SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,82397,SDO_POINT_TYPE(LAT, LONGI,0),NULL,NULL),
                    4326).SDO_POINT.Y)
                   INTO retVAL
          FROM DUAL;
```

so i have the code above that convert the coordinates of a point but how can i do it in a polygon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do. But if you want to transform a polygon, you just use the same SDO_CS.TRANSFORM function.

Assuming a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE US_STATES (
  STATE_CODE CHAR(2),
  GEOM SDO_GEOMETRY
)
```

You can transform the geometries like this:

```
SELECT SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(GEOM,4326) FROM US_STATES;
```

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could up vote my answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: i already upvote it but it did not display because i dont have enough reputation

Comment: Ah OK. Didn't know that. Glad to have helped anyway.